The expected value of betting with Geometric distribution Game
Here we have 0.044 or 4.4% successfull rate with CDF formula $ P(X<=x) = (1-(1-p)^x) $
The reward price is A and the cost per trial is B
$ A = 130000000000 $
$ B = (3000000)(3670) x + (2850000)(1)x + (4000000)(20)x $
The expected value = $(1-(1-0.044)^x)(A) - (1-(1-(1-0.044)^x))(B) $
After plugin some value with interval $ 0<=x<=40 $
We find that we get negative expected value before 20 something
However we get positive expected value after 30 something and max in 40
Question:

Is it the right way to caculate the expected value with Geometric distribution?
I used P(X<=3) this mean we are not force to trial exactly 3 times
If yes what is the best statergy to play the bet? should we play the bet until 40?

